# Loop in react hides other elements

Tags: reactjs

I have this in the render function: (coffee-script)

```
unless @state.loaded
  React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Loading')
else
  React.createElement('h1', {}, 'Blog')
  for year in @blogYears()
    React.createElement(BlogYear, {year: year, content: @state.content, key: year})
```

The `h1` isn't rendered at all, but if I comment out the loop it renders the `h1`. I don't see any sign of the `h1` in the react dev tools.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm not sure about coffee-script syntax, but are you returning React.createElement call result from your render function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the last executed statement will be returned, in your case that is the result of the for loop.

Solution: Wrap the h1 and the loop in a div.

Tip: You can write more Coffeescript-ish code (not tested):

```
React.DOM.div {},
  React.DOM.h1 {}, 'Blog'
  @blogYears.map (year) ->
    React.createElement BlogYear,
      year: year
      content: @state.content
      key: year
```